# String validation not working for custom form

Tags: forms

Please help me with Drupal 8 validation for string.

```
   $form['field_text'] = array(

  '#type'  => 'textfield',

  '#title' => $this->t('Name'),

  '#attributes' => array(' type' => 'alpha' ), 

   );

  $form['field_phone'] = array(

  '#type' => 'textfield',

  '#title' => $this->t('Phone'),

  '#attributes' => array(' type' => 'number' ), 

  );
```

I am able to validate Phone no but not string .

Please suggest what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add validate form function for same.

public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$field_text))

{

  drupal_set_message("MESSAGE_TO_ENTER_STRING_CHARACTERS");        

}
```